# How can I partially specialize a class template for ALL enums?

Tags: c++, enums, template-specialization

Say I have some class template:

```
template<typename T>
class {
// ....
}
```

I can partially specialize this template for **ALL** pointers by:

```
template<typename T>
class<T *> {
// ....
}
```

Can I somehow specialize the template for **ALL** enums? i.e., do something like:
(this doesn't work, though)

```
template<typename T>
class<enum T> {
// ....
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

use C++11 and SFINAE.

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, typename = void>
struct Specialize
{
};

template<typename T>
struct Specialize<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value>::type>
{
   void convert() { }
};

enum E
{
};

int main()
{
   Specialize<E> spec;
   spec.convert();
}
```

Without C++11 use `boost::enable_if` and `boost::is_enum`

Comment: @qwer1304 function template specializations is not good idea. You cannot partial specialize function templates, only explicit specializations.

Comment: This scheme works fine for classes, but I have trouble using it with function templates, e.g.:

template <typename U, typename = void> U f(int i);

template<typename U, typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<U>::value, U>::type> U f(int i)

{

   ...;

}

enum myenum {A,B,C,D};

main () {

   myenum xx;

   xx = f<myenum>(1); // [1]

   xx = f<myenum,myenum>(2); // [2]

}

With gcc 4.7.2 and using -std=c++11, [1] results in undefined reference to 'myenum f<myenum,void>(int)' and [2] in undefined reference to 'myenum f<myenum,myenum>(int)'.

Ideas?

Comment: @qwer1304 use some kind of overload. Like this for example http://liveworkspace.org/code/84c8a46e254f91599261dd6068821e0d

Comment: The liveworkspace.org thing is gone. How does the overload look like?

Comment: @B3ret Same here.. link doesnt work, that's why is important to copy the code also in stackoverflow. Did you find out how to do it for functions?

Comment: I think that's "tag dispatch" (in case the new link dies later)

Comment: If I add the same `convert` function to the generic class `Specialize`, the program still compiles, which I expected is an "ambiguous error", as the generic version and the specialized version both match the initialization `Specialize<E> spec`. May anyone please explain this behavior?

Comment: Sorry, I finally noticed there is **no second parameter** of `std::enable_if`, so for enum types, it should be `Specialize<E, void>`, but not what I thought `Specialize<E, E>` before, and it's the specialization of the generic version. And for non-enum types, this specialization does not exist.