# How can I partially specialize a class template for enums values?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae, template-specialization

can templates be specialized based on enum values

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, typename = void>
struct Specialize
{
};

template<typename T>
struct Specialize<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value>::type>
{
    void convert() { }
};

enum E
{
};

int main()
{
    Specialize<E> spec;
    spec.convert();
}

// My doubt: is below code valid? if not how to achieve this?

enum E
{
    E1,
    E2
};

int main()
{
    Specialize<E, E1> spec;
    spec.convert();
}
```

This is a follow-up question to the answer to the below question.

[How can I partially specialize a class template for ALL enums?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12726954/how-can-i-partially-specialize-a-class-template-for-all-enums?noredirect=1&lq=1#)

I have copy pasted the code from the answer to the question linked above.

I am getting the following error with my changes.

```
error: type/value mismatch at argument 2 in template parameter list for _template<class T, class>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> // My doubt: is below code valid?
>
> `Specialize<E, E1> spec;`

Short answer: No.

Long answer.

You have defined `Specialized` as a template `struct` receiving two **types** template parameters

```
template<typename T, typename = void>
struct Specialize
{
};
```

`E` is a type but `E1` is a **value**.

> if not how to achieve this?

If you want that your `struct`/`class` receive, as template parameters, a type and a value of that type, enabling the specialization of the `struct`/`class` iff (if and only if) the type is an enum, you have to add the `typename = void` as third template parameter

```
template<typename T, T Val, typename = void>
struct Specialize
{
};

template<typename T, T Val>
struct Specialize<T, Val, typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value>::type>
{
    void convert() { }
};
```

Starting from C++17 you can also use `auto` as type for the template value and remove the first template parameter

```
template<auto Val, typename = void>
struct Specialize
{
};

template<auto Val>
struct Specialize<Val, std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum_v<decltype(Val)>>>
{
    void convert() { }
};
```

**-- EDIT --**

The OP asks

> how would we define the function "convert" outside the struct/class?

Unfortunately I don't see a way, in this case, to avoid the `std::enable_if` repetition

```
template <typename T, T Val>
struct Specialize<T, Val,
   typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value>::type>
 { void convert(); };

template <typename T, T Val>
void Specialize<T, Val,
   typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value>::type>::convert ()
 { };
```

Comment: how would we define the function "convert" outside the struct/class? 
Specialize<T, Val, typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value>::type>::convert() 
{ }

Comment: @VinKris - answer improved; hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Your compiler tells you that `Specialize<E, E1> spec;` is invalid.

You can use [`std::integral_constant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant) to wrap a value in a type.

```
template<typename T, T V>
struct Specialize<std::integral_constant<T, V>, typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value>::type>
{
    void convert() { }
};

int main()
{
    Specialize<std::integral_constant<E, E1>> spec;
    spec.convert();
}
```